# Why can't I delete a constraint in xCode for iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode

In the "conflicting constraints" it tells me to delete a constraint. Infuritatingly I can only select one of the two conflicting constraints. The other one, I cannot delete. In fact, it doesn't even exist in the storyboard.

Comment: Could you add an image of your storyboard with the particular object selected please? Might help figure out the issue.

Comment: Infuriatingly when I restarted xcode I could not reproduce the issue.

Comment: Typical! At least it is working.

Comment: Okay it happened again: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByBotxOxRJkDVENJd1lKc1p2dTA

Comment: okay, I think it's because items in stackview are mandated to be the spacing defined in the stackview and in that particular stackview it was 0. I changed it to 10 and the spacing was 10. I think I can work with that

Comment: That would certainly make sense. Glad its sorted